# Flash player + YouTube HD = crashing plugin

Tags: firefox, flash, youtube, html5

I've installed Ubuntu with Wubi, on my WinXP system. I cannot seem to get YouTube videos to play in HD (using Firefox 6) without crashing.

I tried gnash first, but that did not seem to be quite functional. I could not jump ahead in the video, control sound, etc. So I decided to try out Adobe's flash. It works fine, except for HD video, where it plays for a little while, then freezes the video (and Firefox) while the audio keeps running, then after a while, the flash player crashes and I get the sad face "Flash player has crashed // Send error report".

When running Windows I have no problem playing YouTube videos. At least not most of the time..

I have searched around for an answer, but not found anything that works. I have for example disabled hardware acceleration, and tried using https://www.youtube.com. Using **HTML5** on YouTube seems to work, but that does not seem to be available for all videos.

I don't know what specs are important, so please ask if you need something else.

If anyone has ideas, alternative flash players, workarounds, or places to look for possible answers/support, I'd be very grateful.

**Update:**

Specs as requested in comment. Running Windows XP/Ubuntu 11.04 on a laptop (3-4 years old):

```
INTEL CORE2DUO T9300 2.5GHZ 800/6M BOX
2 x Kingston 2GB 667MHZ DDR2 NON-ECC CL5 SODIMM

CHIPSET Intel GM965
PROCESSOR   Intel® Core 2 
GRAPHICS CARD   NVIDIA GeForce Go 8600M GT
GRAPHICS CARD MEMORY (MAX)  512 MB
```

**Update:**

Apparently it was a Firefox problem, because using Chromium seems to work with flash player & YouTube HD. RobinJ's comments helped me fix this one.

Comment: You should post the usual hardware specs - CPU, graphics, RAM. Disabling hardware acceleration is most certainly a bad idea. Given that you have Windows XP installed, the computer is probably an old desktop or a netbook, and most likely doesn't have the power needed to play HD flash content.

Comment: @mike It's a laptop, it's a few years old. Windows 7 was not out, so I picked XP over Vista. 1080p stutters, but 720p plays flawlessly. In Windows. There is no notable difference having hardware acceleration on or off. Added some specs to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login and enable the HTML5 player here http://www.youtube.com/html5.
Haven't got a Youtube account? Put `&html5=True` behind the video URL.

Comment: I have done that, but like I said, it does not seem to be available for all videos, only some.

Comment: In fact, I've only seen it once so far, so my saying that "it works" is making generalisations based on a rather small sample.

Comment: I have only seen one video that didn't support it... Maybe Firefox doesn't support the rigth file format? Why not give Google Chrome a try then? That's what I'm using and it works.

Comment: Well, it says FF4 is supported, and I am using 6. Also, I have no support for that h.262 codec. I'll give Chromium a try, seems they are just about the same, except Chromium is open source. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, same thing. Most of my subs' videos are still using the Adobe Flash player instead of html5. One isn't, but that's it.

Comment: Oh, seems that HD is working with flash player & Chromium. I guess that solves it then. Although I am not keen to give up firefox.

Comment: Chromium doesn't include everything that Chrome includes, so it may well be that CHromium doesn't include the right HTML5 codec thingy.

Comment: Ah, right you are. The h.264 codec is missing. Don't see it in the software centre. Oh well, I'll have a look around and see if I can find it.